# Deploying Rails to Heroku on Windows, postrgres error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Rails 3.2.1, Ruby 1.9.3

I can push my app to Heroku, but when I navigate to the page it fails.  This is from the logs:

"Unexpected error while processing request: Please install the postgresql adapter: 'gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter'"

I have already run that command locally and it worked.

I am using sqlite3 for dev, my gemfile looks like this:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
  gem 'thin'
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong/how to fix this?  thank you!

Comment: Ah yes, deploying to Heroku can be really annoying. A couple of preliminary questions:

1. I assume that you ran bundle before pushing to Heroku, correct? If so, did pg install properly?
2. Have you run `heroku run rake db:create` and `heroku run rake db:migrate` after pushing to Heroku?

Comment: @MaxScheiber thanks for your response!  I did run bundle install before pushing, it seemed to work.  When I run "heroku run rake db:create" I get  "Please install the postgresql adapter: 'gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter' (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile)"

Comment: This is just a guess, but it's possible that since pg is a production gem, it's not being bundled on your local server. Try "heroku run bundle" and see what happens.

Comment: @MaxScheiber I tried that, it seemed to complete successfully, but "heroku run db:create" still gives the same error message.  However, in the list of gems output by "heroku run bundle", i do NOT see "pg". it is in my Gemfile and it shows up in the list when i run bundle locally. i also tried taking out sqlite3 entirely and using "pg" in all environments, same problem.  any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same sort of error with the same sort of config.

```
2013-04-05T08:06:12+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2013-04-05T08:06:12+00:00 app[web.1]: !! Unexpected error while processing request: Please install the postgresql adapte
r: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)
```

Have found that doing an update to the Gemfile (just adding whitespace) gets around the problem. It's a hassle though since it needs to be done every time any change is done.